# statistics packages for Common Lisp

Tags: r, statistics, lisp, common-lisp

I have been looking for some good statistics package for Common Lisp, that should be both stable and efficient. There is [lhstats](http://nostoc.stanford.edu/jeff/cllib/lhstats.lisp), but it doesn't have much documentation and it's not currently maintained. So what is the preferred way for statistics programming in Common Lisp (I'm using SBCL)? I'm looking for a package with advanced statistical functions, such as SEM (structural equation modeling), canonical correlations, GLM (general linear model) etc., but also even very basic but stable and well-documented statistical packages would be useful. Calling R statistical functions from Common Lisp would also be one option. What do you recommend?

Comment: Why does it have to be Common Lisp?  I think you will find R not very hard to learn coming from a Lisp background, and that way you won't be trying to reinvent the wheel....

Comment: Yes, I was actually thinking of R, it has very good statistical functions and and I know the the basics of R syntax. I was looking for a Common Lisp solution, because it's more suitable for general-purpose programming IMHO, but maybe it's good to use R for statistics anyway, through [RCL](http://common-lisp.net/project/rcl/) or [RCLG](http://common-lisp.net/project/rclg/).

Comment: I think, if you find a good Common Lisp solution, you shouldn't go for R, just because it's common to use it for statistics. There's also an interesting article from R creator on the topic of Lisp use for stats: http://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~ihaka/downloads/Compstat-2008.pdf But if you'll decide to use R, you might want to look at swankr (a SWANK backend for R): http://common-lisp.net/~crhodes/swankr/

Comment: @VsevolodDyomkin: I have read that article before and mostly I agree with it. Especially the issues of lack of multi-threading and relative numerical inefficiency of R when compared to Common Lisp are big issues for intensive numerical calculations, and for that reason using R for intensive numerical calculations is not an attractive option. For numerically non-intensive statistics using R does fine.

Comment: common-lisp-stat is developed, just slowly. Personal challenges with the family have slowed me down. But I'm happy to take questions at blindglobe@gmail.com.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Probably, you should look at [common-lisp-stat](https://github.com/blindglobe/common-lisp-stat)

Comment: I was thinking of this option too, but then met some difficulties with installation: I used `git clone` to get the repository and did according to the [Fast Start instructions](https://github.com/blindglobe/common-lisp-stat), but then I get error: `"Component :RSM-STRING not found, required by #<SYSTEM "cls">"`. So I need [rsm-string](https://github.com/blindglobe/rsm-string-cls), and it's not available by using `(ql:system-apropos "rsm")` (`common-lisp-stat` isn't either, for that matter). So how should I install `rsm-string` to be able to use `common-lisp-stat`?

Comment: you can get it (as well as another dependency: listoflists) and install manually from the same author's github account https://github.com/blindglobe. And you;ll also need cldoc from https://github.com/danlentz/cldoc (just like in the old days :) And you'll also need libgfortran3, libblas and liblapack.

Answer (score 6):

The [GNU Scientific Library](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/) has statistics functions and is accessible from [GNU Scientific Library for Lisp](http://common-lisp.net/project/gsll/).

Answer (score 4):

I think I would go with lhstat, it may not be maintained anymore, but the same thing seems true for [common-lisp-stat](https://github.com/blindglobe/common-lisp-stat) (last commit is 1 year old), and at least it is available through Quicklisp. Moreover, maybe those packages aren't maintained because they're good enough.

You can also try [RCL](http://common-lisp.net/project/rcl/) a FFI binding of R which is also quickloadable.

Comment: @VsevolodDyomkin: How do you know? Though even if it's maintained I would go with something quickloadable if it fits my needs, unless there is another system which far better (but then I would probably try to add it to Quicklisp).

Comment: I see the activity of its mainatiner on github. But surely the system should get into quicklisp (it actually is present in https://github.com/quicklisp/quicklisp-projects, but somehow not available). Probably we should file an issue to blindglobe (and xach) to make it available.

Answer (score 1):

I only know of it by name, but look here http://incanter.org/

It calls itself "a Clojure-based, R-like platform for statistical computing and graphics." Where clojure is a variant of common lisp.

Comment: Interesting. Clojure is a variant of Lisp (as are Common Lisp, Scheme and Emacs Lisp etc.) but AFAIK it doesn't comply with **Common Lisp** ANSI standard and IMHO it is also too different from it to be considered a variant of common Lisp (however I haven't tried Clojure yet).

Comment: Clojure isn't a variant of Common Lisp. It's a separate language, with Lisp-like syntax, based on Java and the functional paradigm.

Comment: Agree with other comments that Clojure isn't Common Lisp. I would add though that Incanter is pretty good - I've used it very effectively for data visualizations and it's well worth considering if the requirement is Lisp in general rather than specifically Common Lisp